# Add or substract negative numbers in C

Tags: c, arrays, int

So i've been trying to do a code that adds the integers of a row in an array (this integers can be negative for example)

So you will have something like this:

```
input:
3 2 (Number of rows and columns)
12 7
-3 6
-2 -5

output:
19
3 
-7
```

What I've done is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
static int array[10][10];
int i, j, m, n, sum = 0;

printf("Enter the order of the matrix\n");
scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);
printf("Enter the co-efficients of the matrix\n");
for (i = 0; i < m; ++i)
{
    for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
        scanf("%d", &array[i][j]);
    }
}
for (i = 0; i < m; ++i)
{
    for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
        sum = sum + array[i][j] ;
    }
    printf("%d\n",sum);
    sum = 0;
}
}
```

I can't find a way to "add" negative numbers, what should I change/add to this code? Thanks again :)

Comment: What's wrong with the `+` operator?

Comment: Negative integers are handled just as they should be by using `+`. eg `a + b == 3` where `a == 6` and `b == -3`

Comment: Your program is behaving correctly: -3+6=3 and -2+(-5)=-7, or do you expect something else?

Comment: I believe the output shown is the desired output. OP - what output is your program giving?

Comment: Well I consider myself an idiot, I used one %d and printed i first rather than the sum, so thats why I wasn't getting the desired results. Thanks again everyone.

Comment: I executed your code and got correct answer. What's problem you got? @acm1pt2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
    int array[10][10];
    int i, j, m, n, sum = 0;

    printf("Enter the order of the matrix\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);

    printf("Enter the co-efficients of the matrix\n");
    for (i = 0; i < m; ++i){
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j){
            scanf("%d", &array[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < m; ++i){
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j){
            sum = sum + array[i][j] ;
        }
        printf("%d\n",sum);
        sum = 0;
     }
    return 0;
}
```